# How to select a value from array randomly for a 2d game (not min, max)

Tags: javascript, select, random, 2d

I am making a snake game: if the snake eats the apple, it will spawn randomly in one of the corners.

I tried code like `getRandomInt(0, 25)`, but is spawned in the range of 0 to 25:
(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, ...25)

Code I used:

```
var grid = 16;

if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
    snake.maxCells++;        
    apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
    apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
```

I want the apple to spawn randomly in one of the 4 corners of the map (2d)

at x = 25 or 0

or

at y=  25 or 0

not: x,y at  1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or.. 24

Comment: Please format the code nicely!

Comment: What is the meaning of `grid` and why is it 16?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your grid is `grid` then don't hard-code 25 in your code, but use that variable.

You need only a choice between two values, so:

```
apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 1) * grid;
```

Assuming `getRandomInt` works like that. To be sure, you can do it with the native `Math.random` function also:

```
apple.x = (Math.random() >= 0.5) * grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() gives you 0-0.99999999 (not sure about precision), then you can multiply it by number you want.

Math.random() * 2 gives you number from 0-2 (excluding 2),
Math.random() * 100 gives you number from 0-99.999999.. (not 100)

You can make this float an int by using Math.floor()
...Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) ... so you get number from 0 to 99

Try using this in your file, to get a clue ^^

```
<script>
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
}
</script>
```